# Add attributes to WebBrowser Navigated event

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have 9 WebBrowsers and they all have the same Navigated event. Am I able to add extra attributes to the event? E.g a string:

```
webBrowser1.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w1");
webBrowser2.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w2");
webBrowser3.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w3");
webBrowser4.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w4");
webBrowser5.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w5");
webBrowser6.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w6");
webBrowser7.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w7");
webBrowser8.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w8");
webBrowser9.Navigated += webBrowserAll_Navigated("w9");
```

If so how do I do this? Otherwise is there a way for me to tell what what WebBrowser is currently using the webBrowserAll_Navigated function?
e.g

```
private void webBrowserAll_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    string test;
    if(WebBrowser == WebBrowser1)
    {
       test = w1String
    }
    else if(WebBrowser == WebBrowser2)
    {
       test = w2String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built in: `object sender` is the `WebBrowser` that triggered the event.

```
private void webBrowserAll_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    if (browser == WebBrowser1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```